# Google Books Api - No value for imageLinks - Android JSONException

Tags: java, android, json, google-books, jsonexception

I'm using `Google Books Api` to show list of books, but when I try to get thumbnail url from `imageLinks` `JSONObject`, then the `JSONException` says that there's no value for `imageLinks` even though the value exists in this object.

I tried methods like `JSONObject.isNull()` or `optString()` instead of `getString()`, but it still doesn't give me any value.

Here's the URL that I'm trying to get data from: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android

Here's the code:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
  if (response != null) {
   try {
    JSONArray jsonItemsArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonItemsArray.length(); i++) {
     String thumbnailUrl = "";
     String title = "";
     JSONObject item = jsonItemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
     JSONObject volumeInfo = item.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
     JSONObject thumbnailUrlObject = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
     if (!thumbnailUrlObject.isNull("thumbnail")) {
      thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrlObject.getString("thumbnail");
     }
     title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
     bookList.add(new Book(title, thumbnailUrl));
     booksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

   } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
 @Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
  error.printStackTrace();
 }
});
```

And this is a piece of the JSON response:

```
"kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 500,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "JUVjAgAAQBAJ",
   "etag": "kbnCYPNPKq4",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/JUVjAgAAQBAJ",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Android. Podstawy tworzenia aplikacji",
    "authors": [
     "Andrzej Stasiewicz"
    ],
    "publisher": "Helion",
    "publishedDate": "2013-11-10",
    "description": "Na szczęście dostępna jest już książka Android.",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9788324688418"
     },
     {
      "type": "ISBN_10",
      "identifier": "8324688412"
     }
    ],
    "readingModes": {
     "text": true,
     "image": true
    },
    "pageCount": 216,
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "categories": [
     "Computers"
    ],
    "averageRating": 4.0,
    "ratingsCount": 1,
    "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
    "allowAnonLogging": true,
    "contentVersion": "1.4.4.0.preview.3",
    "imageLinks": {
     "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JUVjAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
     "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JUVjAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
    }
```

And I wonder why does `volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks")` give me `JSONException` with No value for, even though the `imageLinks` has value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every `volumeInfo` node has `imageLinks` node, so you need to check whether given node exists using `node.has` method or `node.opt*` method and checking if result is not `null`. Below you can find safe way hot to get `thumbnail` node:

```
JSONObject thumbnailUrlObject = volumeInfo.optJSONObject("imageLinks");
if (thumbnailUrlObject != null && thumbnailUrlObject.has("thumbnail")) {
    thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrlObject.getString("thumbnail");
}
```

Simple console app which shows how it works:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class OrgJsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        String json = String.join("", Files.readAllLines(jsonFile.toPath()));

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(json);

        // get items
        JSONArray jsonItemsArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonItemsArray.length(); i++) {
            String thumbnailUrl = "";
            JSONObject item = jsonItemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeInfo = item.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            JSONObject thumbnailUrlObject = volumeInfo.optJSONObject("imageLinks");
            if (thumbnailUrlObject != null && thumbnailUrlObject.has("thumbnail")) {
                thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrlObject.getString("thumbnail");
            }
            String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
            System.out.println("title => " + title);
            System.out.println("thumbnail => " + thumbnailUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code for your `JSON` payload prints:

```
title => Android Aplikacje wielowątkowe techniki przetwarzania
thumbnail => 
title => Android. Receptury
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=pZ5iAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
title => Android. Podstawy tworzenia aplikacji
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JUVjAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
title => Optymalizacja wydajności aplikacji na Android
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=WJ1iAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
title => Inteligentny dom. Automatyzacja mieszkania za pomocą platformy Arduino, systemu Android i zwykłego komputera
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=koiKAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
title => Android UI. Podręcznik dla projektantów. Smashing Magazine
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=HEJjAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
title => Android. Programowanie gier na tablety
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=7J1iAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
title => Profesjonalne tworzenie gier internetowych dla systemu Android w językach HTML5, CSS3 i JavaScript
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=vlNjAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
title => Beginning Android 2
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=2XeNswkT_2YC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
title => Pro Android 2
thumbnail => http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Bam8K5SIiTkC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
```

Comment: Still isn't working. As you can see in the json response that I included in this question, the volumeInfo node has imageLinks node and it contains thumbnail with a url. When I'm debugging this, the json response contains the imageLinks with a url in thumbnail node, but when the app is running, it still shows no value for imageLinks

Comment: @rradzzio, if you count `"volumeInfo"` nodes you will see `11` nodes. If you count `"thumbnail"` nodes you will see only `9`. So, some `volumeInfo` does not have `thumbnail`.

Comment: Okay, but it shows me that every ` "volumeInfo" ` does not have ` "thumbnail" ` even though some volumeInfos have it

Comment: @rradzzio, take a look on simple app I added to my answer. It shows properly (without exceptions) `title` and `thumbnail` properties.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Please take a look on [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)